# TensorFlowRecord structure

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition, tensorflow-datasets

I have a csv file with four columns:

1. Path to the image file
2. Image Feature 1
3. Image Feature 2
4. Label for the image

I converted the `.csv` files into `tensorflowRecords` (every 100 rows constructing one `TFrecord` File) and now I am trying to train a model using the `tfRecord` Files.

**What should the structure of the tfrecord file be?** Should it contain only the images and the features, or do I need to separate the labels and feed them to the model on their own? If so, how do I map the labels with the corresponding images in the `tensorflowRecord` files. Currently the structure of the tensorflow Example is :

```
features {
    feature {
        key: "image"
        value {
            bytes_list {
                value: "\377\330\377\340\......." (too long to attach here)
    }}}
    feature {
        key: "feature1"
        value {
            float_list {
                value: 601456.0
    }}}
    feature {
        key: "feature2"
        value {
            float_list {
                value: 33321.0
    }}}
    feature {
        key: "label"
        value {
            bytes_list {
                value: "Tumor"
    }}}
}
```

Comment: If you tend to use all four features (the image, `feature1` and `feature2`, and the label) in the same training process, it's probably easiest to pack them together into a single record, like you have in your example. I'd probably put more than 100 records per file, to avoid filesystem overheads, but that really depends on the total number of records (and size of each record).

Comment: Do you mean that this example is like a tensor (representing each row in my csv file ) and i can create 100 such examples iterating through 100 rows of my csv files and create one single tensorRecord file?

Comment: Sort of: if you make a record for each row of your CSV file (with those four columns), when you use `tf.parse_single_example()` you'll get four tensors corresponding to the four columns.